# How do I randomize a Session ID?

Tags: php, session, random

I want my sessions to create random ids.  I want to use this:

```
session_regenerate_id()
```

What I have now, are these two parts:

```
<?php
session_start();

function confirm_logged_in() {
        if (!logged_in()) {
            redirect_to("login.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sessions, by default, generate a unique id whenever a new one is started.

Comment: So what is the session_regenerate_id() for?

Comment: session_regenerate_id keeps the information stored on the session and replaces the actual id for a new one you can read more on the [php manual entry related to the command:](http://my1.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php)